# How to compare 3 DataFrame in 1 DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have 3 datasets `df1`, `df2`, `df3` and each of these have number of rows and number of columns and I would like to have 1 DataFrame which will show these numbers, for example:

[image]

How can I create DataFrame like above?

Comment: Can you be a bit clear ? If you want to merge the dataframes, you could look into the `merge` function in pandas - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following line of code

```
pd.DataFrame({'df1': df1.shape, 'df2': df2.shape, 'df3': df3.shape}, index=['rows', 'columns'])
```

#### Simple Example

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df1 = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df2 = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
df3 = sns.load_dataset('mpg')

pd.DataFrame({'df1': df1.shape, 'df2': df2.shape, 'df3': df3.shape}, index=['rows', 'columns'])

#          df1  df2  df3
# rows     150  891  398
# columns    5   15    9
```